# Creating a new connective in Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In the exercise below, is included a new connective ($\sqsubset$), and I'm stuck in how to deal with it.

We can view the relation $\vDash$ $\varphi$ → $\psi$ as a kind of ordering. Put $\varphi$ $\sqsubset$ $\psi$ := $\vDash \varphi \rightarrow \psi \space and \nvDash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$.

(i) For each $\varphi, \psi$ such that $\varphi \sqsubset \psi$, find $\sigma$ with $\varphi \sqsubset \sigma \sqsubset \psi$.

I suppose, it's need to prove: 
$\varphi \rightarrow \sigma$ and $\sigma \nrightarrow \varphi$,
$\sigma \rightarrow \psi$ and $\psi \nrightarrow\sigma$

Considering $\varphi \sqsubset \psi := \space\vDash\varphi\rightarrow\psi$ and $\nvDash \psi\rightarrow\varphi$, we can write:

$\varphi \sqsubset\psi \leftrightarrow(\varphi\rightarrow\psi)\space\land\space\lnot\space(\psi\rightarrow\varphi)$

$$\begin{array}{rcc|c|cccc} 
(\varphi & \rightarrow & \psi ) &\land & \lnot & (\psi&\rightarrow&\varphi)  \\ \hline
\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\ 
\ 0&1&1&1&1&1&0&0 \\
\ 1&0&0&0&0&0&1&1 \\
\ 1&1&1&0&0&1&1&1 \\ 
\end{array}$$

So, we can define the truth table of $\space\sqsubset$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc} 
\sqsubset & 0 & 1   \\ \hline
\ 0&0&1 \\ 
\ 1&0&0 \\
\end{array}$$

The problem is find $\sigma$ such that $\varphi\sqsubset\sigma\sqsubset\psi$

Truth table:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c|ccc} 
(\varphi & \sqsubset&\sigma)&\land&(\sigma&\sqsubset&\psi)   \\ \hline
\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
\ 0&0&0&0&0&1&1 \\
\ 0&1&1&0&1&0&0 \\
\ 0&1&1&0&1&0&1 \\
\ 1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
\ 1&0&0&0&0&1&1 \\
\ 1&0&1&0&1&0&0 \\
\ 1&0&1&0&1&0&1 \\
\end{array}$$

We found a contradiction, so we can conclude $\sigma = \bot$

Is this a right way? I'm a bit confusing about the symbol $\sqsubset.$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I suspect (i) has a typo, in that you probably intended $\varphi \sqsubset \sigma \sqsubset \psi$ rather than $\varphi \sqsubset \sigma \sqsubset \varphi$. Also, please review [ask], and add your own approach to the problem.

Comment: Right @KevinQuirin. Edited. Thanks

Comment: What did you get asked to do for the exercise?

Comment: @KevinQuirin, I found $\sigma$ = $\bot$.

Comment: I found the thru table for ⊏, developing φ ⊏ ψ = (φ → ψ) ∧ ¬ (ψ → φ): (0, 0 = 0), (0, 1 = 1), (1, 0 = 0), (1, 1 = 0). Then I found a contradiction in  (φ ⊏ σ) ∧ (σ ⊏ ψ). But I really not sure about my method.

Comment: @RicardoBrandão: the argument in your last comment is quite correct. Another way of saying it is that $\phi \sqsubset \psi$ is true iff $\phi$ is logically strictly stronger than $\psi$ and in two-valued logic that means that $\phi$ is false and $\psi$ is true and there is nowhere left for $\sigma$ to go.

Comment: Thanks @RobArthan. A doubt about good practices here in the site: now I just know the answer, could I post an answer with all paths to achieve the value?

Comment: I think it's fine to collate what you're learnt and post your own answer.

Comment: @RobArthan, I posted the answer.

Comment: @RobArthan That's not true - just because there are only two truth values, does not mean there are only two *formulas*. A better way to think about it: the Boolean algebra of all propositional sentences (in some fixed set of variables) modulo semantic equivalence has many more than 2 elements. See my answer below.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: you are quite right. I was looking at what the OP was doing with truth tables but the original problem requires a deeper analysis.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the language with only one fundamental proposition $P$, and take $\varphi = \perp$, $\psi = P$, then $\varphi \sqsubset \psi$ but it is clear that no formula referring to $P$ alone can lie between them.

So in general (i) is true only if you are allowed to introduce a new propositional letter, and then the formula $\sigma$ needs to have value $T$ everywhere in the new truth table that $\varphi$ does, but not everywhere that $\psi$ does.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a lot of confusion here. I'm going to give a full solution to this problem, and I encourage the OP to figure out why they're own argument does not work.

HTFB's answer is correct. Moreover, although they don't state this explicitly their argument generalizes to arbitrary *finite* alphabets: in the propositional language $\{P_1,...,P_n\}$, take $\varphi=\perp$ and $\psi=P_1\wedge...\wedge P_n$ (for example). So we have to assume we're working in a propositional language with *infinitely many* propositional variables.

Under this assumption, things work out as desired. Given $\varphi\sqsubset\psi$, we can let $P$ be a propositional variable not occurring in either $\varphi$ or $\psi$ (since $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are both only finitely long). Now, consider the formula $$\sigma:\quad \varphi\vee (\psi\wedge P).$$ This formula is true whenever $\varphi$ is true, so $\models \varphi\implies \sigma$; meanwhile, since $\varphi\sqsubset\psi$ and $P$ is not involved in $\varphi$ or $\psi$, we can find a truth assignent making $\psi$ and $P$ true but $\varphi$ false. So $\varphi\sqsubset\sigma$.

Meanwhile, it's clear that $\models\sigma\implies\psi$, but the converse is not true: since $P$ isn't used in $\varphi$ or $\psi$, we can find a truth assignment making $\psi$ true but $P$ and $\varphi$ (and hence $\sigma$!) false. (It must be possible to find a truth assignment making $\psi$ true, since otherwise "$\varphi\sqsubset\psi$" would be absurd.) So $\sigma\sqsubset\psi$.

So we are done.

Comment: I understand your solution @NoahSchweber, but there is a case missing. HTFB talked about an alphabet with a single $P$ and you talked about an alphabet with infinitely many propositional variables. What I am trying now is the finite case (greater than 1). If you got any insight it would be very helpful

Comment: @AlexandreTourinho Finite alphabets behave identically to one-symbol alphabets: given a finite alphabet $\{P_1,...,P_n\}$ just set $\varphi=\perp$ as in HTFB's answer and $\psi=P_1\wedge P_2\wedge...\wedge P_n$. I've added this to my answer to clarify, though.

Comment: Hey @NoahSchweber, but I still got a problem. In order to satisfy $\not\vDash \sigma \to \varphi$ and $\not\vDash \psi \to \sigma$, I realized that we must have at least the valuations that lead to $(\varphi, \psi, \sigma) = (F, T, F)$ and $(\varphi, \psi, \sigma) = (F, T, T)$ [only $\sigma$ changing]. In an alphabet with one $P$, there is no way to do this, where HTFB showed only an example for specific $\varphi$ and $\psi$. In an infinitely long alphabet, you showed that there is the wanted $\sigma$ for ani $\varphi$ and $\psi$. However for the finite case, you only showed a specific case

Comment: @AlexandreTourinho No, my previous comment shows how to construct a counterexample for any finite alphabet, following HTFB's counterexample for a one-letter alphabet. I'm not sure what more you're looking for.

Comment: I realize I am insisting, but my point is that OP asked "for each $\varphi, \psi$ such that $\varphi \sqsubset \psi$, find $\sigma$ with $\varphi \sqsubset \sigma \sqsubset \psi$". For the finite case, you indeed showed that there is no such $\sigma$ for the specific $\varphi$ and $\psi$ taken, but what about for others $\varphi$ and $\psi$? I understand that you extended HTFB solution, but I also think HTFB solution isn't complete (however right; there is indeed no way to find $\sigma$ in the unitary finite case)

Comment: @AlexandreTourinho Well, a single counterexample is enough to show that the problem does not work unless we assume that the language is infinite. So this does in fact give a complete solution: if the language is finite then the problem as stated is wrong, while if the language is infinite the solution in my answer applies.

Comment: I agree, and I think a lot got clarified. But I am still in trouble for the finite case because my professor gave me the same exercise but stated "prove or disprove"

Comment: @AlexandreTourinho A single counterexample constitutes a disproof, you don't need to give a complete description of all possibilities.